# How to write a Pine script to get the list of stocks meeting certain criteria?

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine script and a regular user of Tradingview. Shall anybody guide me on how to use the pinescript to get the list of stocks meeting certain criteria?

regards

I have never used the pine script so far. As mentioned above, need to learn how to write a script in pine to get the stocks result

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your condition:

`cond = (close > open)`

Then you need to call the `security()` function to request data from other symbols.

```
ibm_cond = request.security("NYSE:IBM", timeframe.period, cond)
```